# C# Linq to XML - Return multiple children

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Interfaces>
  <Interface>
    <Name>Account Lookup</Name>
    <PossibleResponses>
      <Response>Account OK to process</Response>
      <Response>Overridable restriction</Response>
    </PossibleResponses>
  </Interface>
  <Interface>
    <Name>Balance Inquiry</Name>
    <PossibleResponses>
      <Response>Funds available</Response>
      <Response>No funds</Response>
    </PossibleResponses>
  </Interface>
</Interfaces>
```

I need to retrieve the possible responses for an interface:

```
// Object was loaded with XML beforehand    
public class Interfaces : XElement {
    public List<string> GetActionsForInterface(string interfaceName) {
        List<string> actionList = new List<string>();
        var actions = from i in this.Elements("Interface")
                      where i.Element("Name").Value == interfaceName
                      select i.Element("PossibleResponses").Element("Response").Value;

        foreach (var action in actions)
            actionList.Add(action);

        return actionList;
    }
}
```

The result should be a list such as this (for interface 'Account Lookup'):
Account OK to process
Overridable restriction

But its only returning the first value - 'Account OK to process'. What is wrong here?

Edit:
I changed my method:

```
public List<string> GetActionsForInterface(string interfaceName) {
    List<string> actionList = new List<string>();
    var actions = from i in this.Elements("interface")
                  where i.Element("name").Value == interfaceName
                  select i.Element("possibleresponses").Elements("response").Select(X => X.Value);

    foreach (var action in actions)
        actionList.Add(action);

    return actionList;
}
```

But now I get 2 errors on line 'actionList.Add(action);':

```
The best overloaded method match for System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>' to 'string'
```

I suppose the select many is casting the results into something else then strings?

Edit:
To fix the last error:

```
    foreach (var actions in query)
        foreach(string action in actions)
            actionList.Add(action);
```

Apparently there is an array within an array here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
select i.Element("PossibleResponses").Element("Response")
```

returns the first "response" element. Use [Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.elements.aspx) instead.

You then need to select many to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
static List<string> GetActionsForInterface(string interfaceName)
{
  var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
  List<string> actionList = new List<string>();
  var actions = doc.Root
    .Elements("Interface")
    .Where(x => x.Element("Name").Value == interfaceName).
    Descendants("Response").Select(x => x.Value);

  foreach (var action in actions)
    actionList.Add(action);

  return actionList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.Root.Elements("Interface").Select(e=>new {
 Name = e.Element("Name").Value,
 PossibleResponses = e.Element("PossibleResponses").Elements("Response").select(e2=>e2.Value)
});
```